# Is there a way to iterate time and go back to the function after?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a Pomodoro application with Tkinter. I want to send the work/rest time to a function to countdown the time sent. These work/rest time should loop within the conditioned number of sessions.

My try was to send the values to the function and return after they are done with the time counter. the counter code worked for me when I separated from the code. but the problem I have is with how to return after It's done.

```
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init__window()

        self.remaining = 0
        self.remainingSessions = 0
        
        self.countdownLabel = Label(self, text="", width=10, height=5)
        self.countdownLabel.pack()

        self.work = 5
        self.rest = 3
        self.sessions = 2

        self.startButton = Button(self, text="Start", command= partial(self.sessionsCountdown, self.work, self.rest, self.sessions))
        self.startButton.pack()

    def init__window(self):
        self.master.title("Pomodoro")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def sessionsCountdown(self, remainingWork = None, remainingRest = None, sessions = None):
        self.remainingSessions = sessions

        while self.remainingSessions >= 0:
            print("session number = ", self.remainingSessions)
            self.countdown(remainingWork)
            print("done with work")
            self.countdown(remainingRest)
            print("done with rest")
            self.remainingSessions = self.remainingSessions - 1 

        self.countdownLabel.configure(text="time's up!")
          
    def countdown(self, remaining = None):
        if remaining is not None:
            self.remaining = remaining

        print(remaining)

        if self.remaining <= 0:
            return

        else:
            mins, secs = divmod(self.remaining, 60)
            timer = '{:02}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
            self.countdownLabel.configure(text=timer)
            self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)
```

I wrote some prints for debugging and I keep getting the following output in the terminal

```
session number =  2
5
done with work     
3
done with rest     
session number =  1
5
done with work     
3
done with rest     
session number =  0
5
done with work     
3
done with rest     
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

GUI's work with "event-driven programming", which is very different from the procedural programming that most people learn at first. When you use a function like `self.after` you are scheduling an event to happen later, but allowing other events to happen in the meantime. Important things like responding to clicks and updating the display, but also the little things like moving the window or changing the button color slightly when you hover over it.

To do what you want you'll need to set up some kind of variables to keep track of where you are in the series and use those. I think you know this because you already have those instance variables. All that's left is to trigger the right one in your `if self.remaining <= 0:` clause.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master) # the modern way
        # self.master = master # not needed
        self.init__window()

        self.remaining = 0
        self.remainingSessions = 3
        self.current = None

        self.current_activity = Label(self, text="", width=10, height=5)
        self.current_activity.pack()
        self.countdownLabel = Label(self, text="", width=10, height=5)
        self.countdownLabel.pack()

        self.startButton = Button(self, text="Start", command= self.sessionsCountdown)
        self.startButton.pack()

    def init__window(self):
        self.master.title("Pomodoro")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1) # this line is traditionally not in the class

    def sessionsCountdown(self):
        '''choose the right activity to trigger'''
        if self.remainingSessions <= 0:
            self.current_activity.config(text="Done!")
            self.countdownLabel.configure(text="time's up!")
            return
        else:
            self.remainingSessions -= 1

        if self.current == "resting":
            self.current = 'working'
            self.current_activity.config(text="Working:")
            self.remaining = 5
        else:
            self.current = 'resting'
            self.current_activity.config(text="Resting:")
            self.remaining = 3
        self.countdown() # start the timer again.

    def countdown(self, remaining=0):
        if self.remaining <= 0:
            self.sessionsCountdown()
        else:
            mins, secs = divmod(self.remaining, 60)
            timer = '{:02}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
            self.countdownLabel.configure(text=timer)
            self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)
r = Tk()
Window(r)
r.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this concept worked for me and allowed me to develop more features. it was really easy to understand your code. I am only a little bit confused about the usage of remaining=0 is the countdown function. Can you please tell me why did you add it?

Comment: Ah yes, that's an advanced feature called a "typo". I was going to show a different method of counting down that involves an argument, then decided against that but forgot to remove the argument.

Comment: hahaha, thank you for explaining this feature. It sure is very common. and thank you again for your help